# Mounting a Luks partition

Tags: ubuntu, mount, luks, cryptsetup, loop-device

I have backed up a drive with all its partitions using the command

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/oshirowanen/external-drive/backups-2019/full_drive_backup.img
```

`/dev/sda` is an ssd which has a Linux OS with full encryption.

Before I wipe this drive and re-purpose it, I want to make sure the backup has worked.

I have tried the following by searching unix.stackexchange and other stackexchange sites:

```
sudo losetup -P /dev/loop0 /media/oshirowanen/external-drive/backups-2019/full_drive_backup.img 
[sudo] password for oshirowanen: [password goes here]
losetup: /media/oshirowanen/external-drive/backups-2019/full_drive_backup.img: failed to set up loop device: Device or resource busy

sudo losetup -P /dev/loop100 /media/oshirowanen/external-drive/backups-2019/full_drive_backup.img 
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop100p5 img5
Enter passphrase for /dev/loop100p5: [password goes here]

cd /mnt
mkdir img5
sudo mount /dev/mapper/img5 img5
mount: /mnt/img5: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
```

What am I doing wrong?  Both `cryptsetup` and `lvm2` are already installed.

If this is not the best way to backup the drive, please suggest something else which is better.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is a screenshot of /dev/sda's partitions:

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Output from LiveUSB:

```
liveusb@liveusb:~$ sudo losetup -P /dev/loop100 /media/external-drive/backups-2019/full_drive_backup.img 
liveusb@liveusb:~$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop100p5 img5
Enter passphrase for /dev/loop100p5: 
liveusb@liveusb:~$ cd /mnt
liveusb@liveusb:/mnt$ sudo mkdir img5
liveusb@liveusb:/mnt$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/img5 img5
mount: /mnt/img5: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
liveusb@liveusb:/mnt$ sudo pvscan
  PV /dev/mapper/img5   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [232.16 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [232.16 GiB] / in use: 1 [232.16 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
liveusb@liveusb:/mnt$ sudo vgscan
  Reading volume groups from cache.
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
liveusb@liveusb:/mnt$ sudo vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 232.16g    0 
liveusb@liveusb:/mnt$ sudo lvs
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-a----- <231.21g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-a-----  980.00m                                                    
liveusb@liveusb:/mnt$ ls /dev/mapper/
control  img5  ubuntu--vg-root  ubuntu--vg-swap_1
liveusb@liveusb:/mnt$
```

Comment: Are there any partitions on `/dev/sda`? Is `/dev/sda` encrypted, or are one or more of the partitions encrypted?

Comment: @OlafDietsche, please see screenshot of partitions in OP.  Yes, at least 1 partition is encrypted.

Comment: Ok, does https://askubuntu.com/q/766048/108339 help you here? Particularly `vgscan` and maybe `vgrename`?

Comment: Have you tried `pvs` (physical volumes), `vgs` (volume groups) and `lvs` (logical volumes) to see what the system recognizes?

Comment: @OlafDietsche, please see output in update 2 from liveusb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the image, the partition seems to be a physical volume. This is verified by `pvscan`.

`lvs` lists two logical volumes, one of them a swap partition (LV swap_1) it seems, and the other the actual file system (LV root). This is the relevant one, to be mounted by

```
mount -o ro /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt/img5
```

---

When the devices are missing, [`vgscan --mknodes`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/vgscan.8.html#OPTIONS)

> **--mknodes**
> Also checks the LVM special files in /dev that are needed
> for active LVs and creates any missing ones and removes
> unused ones.

or [`vgmknodes`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/vgmknodes.8.html) might be helpful

> vgmknodes checks the LVM device nodes in /dev that are needed for
> active LVs and creates any that are missing and removes unused
> ones.

Comment: On a debian livesystem: `cryptsetup luksOpen` worked/unlocked the partition but `/dev/mapper` did not contain the volumes `sudo lvs` would see. Even `lvs` was not installed at first, so I did `apt install lvm2`. Turns out you should then __lock the partition and re-run__ `cryptsetup luksOpen` __with lvm2 installed__!

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case the LUKS volume contains a Logical Volume Manager Physical Volume (hence the `LVM2_member` error you received while trying to mount).

The outputs

```
# pvscan
  PV /dev/mapper/img5   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [232.16 GiB / 0    free]
```

and

```
# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 232.16g    0
```

both indicate that the LUKS volume contains (fully) the volume group `ubuntu-vg`, which contains the logical volumes

```
$ sudo lvs
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log  Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-a----- <231.21g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-a-----  980.00m
```

You can mount the filesystem under `root` through the command

```
sudo mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /mnt/img5
```